# New Spotify iOS SDK : Persistent authentication in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I've been using the spotify sdk in my app and recently switched to the new sdk they came out with last september. I followed their quick start guide and was able to get the created project running fine. There are just a few points that I'm not clear on and was hoping someone who's also been using the new sdk could help me out with.

1. I've set up a Heroku server for the token swap. As I understand - an access token is valid for an hour - when the session expires we exchange the refresh token for a new access token - which also lasts an hour - when that expires we exchange the same refresh token again for a new access token - and so on...? Is that right ?
2. Do I have to set up my own functionality to - figure out when my current session is going to expire and accordingly renew it before it expires? Or does the session manager do that automatically once it is set up for OAuthCode grant flow? If so does anyone have suggestions of a good way implementing that ?
3. Everytime I launch my app - it takes me to the spotify app/webview for a brief second to authenticate and brings me back - why does it have to do this every time? Is there any way that - once I grab the token, I store it and check if the token/session is valid or not and continue without doing the switch?